# Expo/React Native image paths from camera

Tags: javascript, react-native, ecmascript-6, expo

I'm using the the [Camera](https://docs.expo.io/versions/latest/sdk/camera/) package in Expo and I'm able to take pictures successfully.

After taking a picture, I get an object back with data

```
Object {
  "height": 4096,
  "uri": "file:///var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/7399B27C-F34B-4B2F-8F58-237D41136EE9/Library/Caches/ExponentExperienceData/asdasdasdefwefw/Camera/C3D87AB5-6B91-4A9E-83FC-DFSFEEWFEFSAFSD.jpg",
  "width": 2304,
},
```

Now in order to display this image, I want to use the `<ImageBackground />` or `<Image />` component. e.g.

```
 <ImageBackground source={require( Object.uri )} />
```

Of cause, the problem with either of these two componenents is that `require`'s [value must be a static path](https://docs.expo.io/versions/latest/react-native/images/#static-image-resources) and it cannot accept variables.

So how can I display the image without saving it to the photo library and using the image picker to open it from the library?

Comment: Can you omit require and use Object.uri directly? require is processed at compile-time, and therefore typically doesn't make sense to use with user input

Comment: Have you tried what is mentioned in the [Local Filesystem Images section](https://docs.expo.io/versions/latest/react-native/images/#local-filesystem-images) of the docs you linked? It points to the [MediaLibrary module](https://docs.expo.io/versions/latest/sdk/media-library/?redirected) which sounds like it would accomplish what you are trying to do.

Comment: Have you tried with source={{   uri: Object.uri    }}

Comment: @vpzomtrrfrt what would the `key` name be, the docs doesn't state one ?.. `source={{key: Object.uri}}

Comment: Not sure where you're getting key from, I would expect just `source={Object.uri}` to work.

Comment: @AlokMali That work, please add it as answer!

Comment: @vpzomtrrfrt if I don't provide a key, it throws an error of `invalid prop 'source' supplied to 'image', so there needs to be a key.

Comment: @AshleyBrown, Yes of course.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using an absolute path of an image than you can do it like below -

```
<ImageBackground source={{uri: Object.uri}} />
```

For an Image with inline-style -

```
<Image style={{ height: 200, resizeMode: 'cover' }} source={{ uri: Object.uri }} />
```

Comment: Your example of ImageBackground doesn't work, both example have to use the `uri` key as described in your second example, which works